# If $\langle a_n \rangle_{n=0}^\infty$ is convergent and $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n=a$, then for every nonprincipal ultrafilter $U$, $\lim_U a_n=a$

Tags: proof-explanation, filters

My textbook *Introduction to Set Theory 3rd* by Hrbacek and Jech introduces a definition related to ultrafilter as follows:

> **2.7. Definition** Let $U$ be an ultrafilter on $\mathbb{N}$, and let $\langle a_n\rangle_{n=0}^{\infty}$ be a bounded sequence of real numbers. We say that a real number $a$ is the *$U$-limit* of the sequence,
>
> $$ a = \lim_{U} a_n, $$
>
> if for every $\epsilon > 0$, $\{n \mid |a_n - a| < \epsilon\} \in U$.
>
> First, we observe that if $U$-limit exists then it is unique. For, assume that $a< b$ and both $a$ and $b$ are $U$-limits of $\langle a_n\rangle_{n=0}^{\infty}$. Let $\epsilon = (b-a)/2$. Then the sets $\{n \mid |a_n - a| < \epsilon\}$ and $\{n \mid |a_n - b| < \epsilon\}$ are disjoint and so cannot both be in $U$.
>
> If $U$ is a principal ultrafilter, $U = \{ A \mid n_0 \in A\}$ for some $n_0$, then $\lim_U a_n = a_{n_0}$, for any sequence $\langle a_n\rangle_{n=0}^{\infty}$. This is because for every $\epsilon > 0$, $\{ n \mid |a_n - a_{n_0}| < \epsilon\} \supseteq \{n_0\} \in U$.
>
> If $\langle a_n\rangle_{n=0}^{\infty}$ is convergent and $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = a$, then for every nonprincipal ultrafilter $U$, $\lim_U a_n = a$. This is because for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists some $k$ such that $\{n \mid |a_n - a| < \epsilon\} \subseteq \{ n \mid n \geq k \}$, and $\{n \mid n \geq k\} \in U$.
>
> The important property of ultrafilter limits is that the $U$-limit exists for every bounded sequence:

There is a statement in the paragraph:

> If $\langle a_n \rangle_{n=0}^\infty$ is convergent and $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n=a$, then for every nonprincipal ultrafilter $U$, $\lim_U a_n=a$. This is because for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists some $k$
> such that $\{n \mid |a_n - a| < \epsilon\} \supseteq \{n \mid n \ge k\}$, and $\{n \mid n \ge k\} \in U$.

Please confirm if my understanding of this paragraph is correct or not! Thank you so much!

---

> **Lemma:** An ultrafilter which contains a finite set is principal.
>
> **Proof:** Let $U$ be an ultrafilter on $X$ and $A\in U$ be finite. Then either there exists some $a \in A$ such that $\{a\} \in U$, implying that $U$ is principal, or else $\{a\} \notin U$ for all $a \in A$ and thus $X- \{a\} \in U$ for all $a \in A$, so $U \ni A \cap \bigcap_{a\in A}(X - \{a\}) =\emptyset$, leading to a contradiction.

It follows from $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n=a$ that $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N \in \Bbb N, \forall n \ge N: |a_n - a| < \epsilon$ and thus $\{n \in \Bbb N \mid |a_n - a| < \epsilon\} \supseteq \{n \in \Bbb N \mid n \ge N\}$.

I claim that there exists $M \in \Bbb N$ such that $M \ge N$ and $\{n \in \Bbb N \mid n \ge M\} \in U$. If not, $\{n \in \Bbb N \mid n \ge M\} \notin U$ for all $M \ge N$. This combining with the fact that $U$ is a ultrafilter implies $\Bbb N - \{n \in \Bbb N \mid n \ge M\} \in U$ or $\{n \in \Bbb N \mid n < M\} \in U$ for all $M \ge N$. As a result, there exists at least a finite set of natural numbers in $U$.  This clearly contradicts to our Lemma.

We have $\{n \in \Bbb N \mid |a_n - a| < \epsilon\} \supseteq \{n \in \Bbb N \mid n \ge N\} \supseteq \{n \in \Bbb N \mid n \ge M\}$ where $\{n \in \Bbb N \mid n \ge M\} \in U$. It follows that $\{n \in \Bbb N \mid |a_n - a| < \epsilon\} \in U$.

Comment: I could not understand why this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/631409/any-ultrafilter-over-a-finite-set-is-principal) gets up to $5$ upvotes, while mine gets downvote. It seems unfair to my question huh.

Comment: Your question is *not* in line with [SE's policy on text images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/155601/259305), which are *not* SEO friendly.

Comment: Your solution is so elegant @SangchulLee. Many thanks!

Comment: I migrated my comment to an answer plus some additional materials. :)

Comment: I replaced the image with text, but you may trim out irrelevant paragraphs so that question looks lighter. :)

Comment: Your effort spent on retyping the image really touches my heart @SangchulLee. All the best for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is good. If you want to utilize  the lemma, however, it would be better to know a more direct argument:

- Assume that $\lim a_n = a$ and $U$ is a non-principal ultrafilter. Our goal is to show that, for each $\epsilon > 0$, the set $A_{\epsilon} = \{ n : |a_n - a| < \epsilon \}$ lies in $U$.

  Since $U$ is an ultrafilter, either $A_{\epsilon}\in U$ or $\mathbb{N}\setminus A_{\epsilon}\in U$. But since $\lim a_n = a$, we know that $\mathbb{N}\setminus A_{\epsilon}$ is finite, and so, cannot lie in $U$ by the lemma. Therefore $A_{\epsilon} \in U$ as required.

Alternatively, we may combine the following several independent facts:

1. If $F \subseteq F'$ are filters and $\lim_F a_n = a$, then $\lim_{F'} a_n = a$.
2. Let $F_{\mathrm{co}} = \{ A \subseteq \mathbb{N} : \mathbb{N}\setminus A\text{ is finite} \}$ be the *Fréchet filter* (a.k.a. cofinite filter). Then $\lim_n a_n = a$ if and only if $\lim_{F_{\mathrm{co}}} a_n = a$.
3. Fréchet filter is contained in every non-principal ultrafilter. (This is a direct consequence of the lemma in OP.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your dedicated help!